# Linphone Compiling - Mingw 64bit - GNU gettext tools not found; required for intltool

Tags: c++, c, 64-bit, mingw, gettext

I am attempting to compile Linphone for Windows, however I receive configure: error: GNU gettext tools not found; required for intltool when I run ./configure --prefix=/opt/linphone --enable-shared --disable-static.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Linphone uses gtk+, right? As far as I know, the precompiled development version of gtk+ for windows should allready include gettext.

Run `./configure --help` to see how to tell configure where to find gtk+ and gettext